# Thread-safe RLockedList

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.x

I have written a thread-safe list which can be used as a drop-in replacement for a regular list. This has been tested and used internally without issue, but "The absence of evidence is not evidence of absence" so even though I have had no issues with using this, do you folks see anything wrong with the code?

Stepping back, here is the original problem and why threading was introduced to help solve it.

In Cisco's ACI solution, the APIC is a central point of management for the network. It features a declarative configuration format which can be queried and updated via it's REST API.

One interesting feature is the ability for clients to [subscribe to a query (scroll up slightly)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/2-x/rest_cfg/2_1_x/b_Cisco_APIC_REST_API_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_APIC_REST_API_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01.html#d25e2796a1635) and receive push notifications via a websocket whenever the result of that query changes.

I have written a class to simplify managing connection state on behalf of clients who are querying the APIC. It is used like this:

```
from MyModule import MySessionClass
session = MySessionClass(my_apic_ip)
session.post('/uni/<some-managed-object-path-here>', payload)
session.subscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo>') # Sends GET request to APIC, appends to RLockedList
session.subscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo_2>')
session.subscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo_3>')
...
session.unsubscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo_2>') # Removes this dn from the RLockedList, after 60s or less we stop receiving push notifications for this query on the websocket.
...
session.unsubscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo>')
session.unsubscribe('/uni/<watch_this_mo_3>')
```

Due to the following requirements, I have introduced threading:

1. We must refresh our API session (via POST) before 5 minutes have passed (in the future, this may have multiple API sessions to refresh due to controller clustering.)
2. We must refresh *each* push-notification subscription we have every minute (or less)
3. We must listen for push notifications and receive them in a timely manner

The above is complicated by the following:

- Excessively large read and update (GET and POST) operations can take minutes to return in some cases. In other cases (e.g the result is still cached on the APIC) the same query will return quickly. Without threads the subscriptions would certainly time out in this case.
- Multiple subscriptions to the same session can be active at one time.
- While one thread is refreshing the subscriptions in the list, another thread may modify the list. It can remove and delete an element from anywhere in the list - usually somewhere in the middle, rather than at the ends.

This thread-safe list will maintain the current list of active subscriptions. The subscription refresh thread will periodically iterate through this list, sending GET requests to the APIC. These generally return in ~1 second and we expect the maximum number of user subscriptions to be 30, though there is no hard restriction on this on the server.

So there is one thread for refreshing the subscriptions, one thread to keep us logged in, and one thread to read the push notifications on the websocket as they come in.

This is the list used to manage subscriptions. Does this implementation of a re-entrant locked list look thread-safe to you? By this, I mean *truly* thread safe, as in thread-safe within an environment with multiple kernel threads (as is seen in Jython, for example) and without the assurance of the Global Interpreter Lock. Most likely, this is fine. But if anyone is an expert in threading in Python, I would appreciate it if you looked this over.

```
import threading

class RLockedList(list):
    def __init__(self, in_list = []):
        self.__in_list = in_list # Internal List
        self.__lock = threading.RLock()

    def __add__(self, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__add__(self.__in_list, x)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__contains__(self.__in_list, item)

    def __class__(self):
        return RLockedList

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__delitem__(self.__in_list, key)

    def __delslice__(self, i, j):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__delslice__(self.__in_list, i, j)

    def __doc__(self):
        return list.__doc__(self.__in_list, i, j)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__eq__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__format__(self.__in_list, format_spec)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__ge__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__getitem__(self.__in_list, i)

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__getslice__(self.__in_list, i, j)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__gt__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __hash__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__hash__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__iadd__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __imul__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__imul__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __iter__(self):
        '''return an iterator to a copy of the list, so that thread-safety is maintained.'''
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__iter__(list(self.__in_list))

    def __le__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__le__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __len__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__len__(self.__in_list)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__lt__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__mul__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__ne__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __reduce__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__reduce__(self.__in_list)

    def __reduce_ex__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__reduce_ex__(self.__in_list)

    def __repr__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__repr__(self.__in_list)

    def __reversed__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__reversed__(self.__in_list)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__rmul__(self.__in_list, other)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__setitem__(self.__in_list, key, value)

    def __setslice__(self, i, j, sequence):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__setslice__(self.__in_list, i, j, sequence)

    def __sizeof__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__sizeof__(self.__in_list)

    def __str__(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__str__(self.__in_list)

    def __subclasshook__(self, subclass):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.__subclasshook__(self.in_list, subclass)

    def append(self, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.append(self.__in_list, x)

    def count(self, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.count(self.__in_list, x)

    def extend(self, L):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.extend(self.__in_list, L)

    def index(self, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.index(self.__in_list, x)

    def insert(self, i, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.insert(self.__in_list, i, x)

    def pop(self, i = -1):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.pop(self.__in_list, i)

    def remove(self, x):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.remove(self.__in_list, x)

    def reverse(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.reverse(self.__in_list)

    def sort(self, _cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False):
        with self.__lock:
            return list.sort(self.__in_list, _cmp, key, reverse)

    def get_list(self):
        '''return a copy of the current state of the thread-safe list.'''
        with self.__lock:
            return list(self.__in_list)
```

Comment: Have you thought about using, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) or [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)?

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @Mast Yes, in fact I have been using it for some time without issues. But if there is a race condition it is possible that I simply haven't encountered it yet.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that doesn't satisfy my requirements because LIFO/FIFO isn't applicable to my case. I know what you are thinking in regards to producer/consumer pattern but I am using this in more of a random access way.

Comment: Please leave an explanation if you downvote. This is 100% original code, made only out of necessity. I previously scoured the internet but could not find a single implementation of a thread-safe list in Python. Queues backed by a list? Yes, those exist. But a list itself? Not a single one. It is my hope that this post will help the next person to come along and need this data structure. If it already exists, please direct me to it since this question is a waste of time. If not, I hope that we can come together as a community to pick out the flaws and make this an example that everyone can use.

Comment: This question lacks description. Can you expand about this code (why, how..); what are its key features; how do you use it? Also, as it stand, to me, this question reads a bit like "please explain this code to me" which is off-topic. It sounds like it is not, but still, I have that feeling; you might want to rephrase that part as well and remember that a review may be about any and all aspect of the code, not necessarily thread safety.

Comment: The originality of your code isn't the problem. The lack of description is. We don't know anything about your problem, so we don't know why other alternatives are unacceptable. You're also asking whether it's thread-safe, while we require you to test such things yourself. Now, 'Yes' or 'No' could be valid answers, which is not helpful to the site. Please take a look at our [FAQ on asking questions.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Fair enough, I've added more info to the description. I'm not looking for explanation, just for the assurance of an expert to reassure me that I haven't missed anything. This seems like such a common pattern, someone out there must have done this before. Other languages have implemented exactly this. I am just too humble to consider myself at the level of those core language developers.

Comment: @Mast I've updated the question significantly, and I've tested the thread-safety myself. In fact this is used by many people internally at my company, with no issues. But since threading issues are notoriously difficult to reproduce and it can be incredibly rare to see them "in the wild", I am seeking more of a theoretical answer here. "Yes, in theory the code is good, but from personal experience this technique won't work on X platform because of reason Z with bug ID 1234" or "No. This is very unlikely but consider <scenario>, your list will not be thread safe in that case."

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13618333) shows a couple of different ways to do roughly what you are doing to a _set_, so it may interest you.

Comment: @Pelionrayz thanks for that link, that is a really great post.